# Dynamic adjust Container height

Tags: flutter, dynamic, containers, size, height

I want to achieve a dynamic height for a Container in the appBar area. (Later, I will add text and icons inside it for animations). Currently, I'm using CustomScrollView and SliverAppBar, and I've placed the Container within a Stack widget. Now, when I scroll down or scroll up my UI, I want the Container to increase and decrease its height. Is this possible in Dart? Thanks!

I have tried using scrollController and see the changes in console which I was able to do it but in UI it wont change the height dynamically when scrolling.

Here's a video of my goal. Any assistance appreciated:
https://www.veed.io/view/0f6682e1-bf6d-4d9d-b1b2-739729e56af7?panel=share

Comment: *increase and decrease its height* You might be looking for  `flexibleSpace` on SliverAppBar. Or you can use `SliverPersistentHeader`.

Comment: You can use [SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate-class.html) . then use `shrinkOffset` with lerp method for positioning widget in Stack.